# API Mail App event APIs

Tags: c#, api, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am looking for information about the WindowsPhone 8 APIs. Are there APIs available to hook into the email and text messaging apps?

For example, if wanted to scan the subject line and sender address of all incoming mail messages, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment there's no Official API that let you do that, All you can do is [Use the email compose task to enable users to send email from your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), note that you also can't attach files, this last feature is said to be [high on the consideration list for future Windows Phone releases.](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/2229899-api-to-create-emails-with-an-attachment)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  The only interaction with mail and SMS functionality on the phone is the ability to launch a task to creat a new message in either form.